# Explanation of the 'If and only if' statement's rules

Tags: logic

I had never had a problem with understanding 'if and only if' statements until I decided to learn some formal logic. And there I found that:

> A compound 'if and only if' statement is true if both of its atomic statements are true or false

[image: rules for iff statements]

If I understood correctly the text and the table, there is a problem with (at least) this statement:

```
Fish can swim if and only if it's August 9.
```

From the formal logic rule cited above this statement is true, since both statements are true. But intuitively it's false. Since fish can swim regardless of today's date.

Also it's definitely false, if we dissect it in two:

- if it's August 9, fish can swim — True
- if fish can swim, it's August 9 — False

Could anyone please explain, what's wrong with my fish example and reasoning? Or if the table at the picture is correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your reasoning is wrong because you are viewing implication as *causation* rather than merely *correlation*. All $A \implies B$ means is that if $A$ is true then $B$ is true; it says nothing about why $B$ is true. (In particular, $B$'s truth may have nothing to do with $A$ at all; e.g. "if $3 = 5$ then I am Patrick Stevens" is true, because I am Patrick Stevens; nothing at all to do with the truth or falsity of $3 = 5$.)

"If fish can swim, then it's August 9th" is true as a statement of logic, because it's August 9th. Of course, it's not true as a statement of English, because the mere fact that fish can swim does not cause it to be August 9th. The "if/then" relationship means something different in formal logic to what it means in English.

Comment: The statement is still only true today - on August 9th. Tomorrow the statement will be false.

Comment: I'd slightly disagree with `if 3=5 then I am Patrick Stevens is true, because I am Patrick Stevens`. This statement is true **not b/c you are Patrick Stevens.** It's true b/c it, virtually, doesn't state who you are and hence it doesn't lie.: 1. it states the fact on one condition. 2. it doesn't state that the condition is true 3. if the condition is not true, the statement virtually doesn't state anything and hence doesn't lie and is true

Comment: It's true for both reasons.

Comment: I agree. I moved slightly forward in the textbook and got the idea, that in an implication if the then statement is true, then it doesn't matter if the if condition is true, because in all cases the value of the if/then statement will be true. **One can test/prove this with a truth table.**